# Facebook Post a tag to another page

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I am using C# winforms and C# Facebook SDK 6 to create an app that control my page and automate somethings.

In all posts in my page i put tags in the text to other pages so i want to know how to post a tag in my page posts using Facebook SDK and Facebook graph API.

I tried the message_tag parameter in different scenarios but it didn't work maybe i am using it wrong, the code below is one of the senarios :

```
dynamic postParameters = new ExpandoObject();

postParameters.message = textToPostTextBox.Text;
postParameters.message_tags = new { id = "page_to_tag_id", name = "PageName", type = "page", offset = 3, length = 4 };
dynamic result = fb.Post("my_page_id/feed", postParameters);
```

Notes : a tag to page is when you type "@" and write the page or person name.

Please help me i searched a lot online and i tried my self but it didn't work and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: You can’t tag in the message of post via API any more (was possible some time ago, but got disabled because of too much abuse).

Comment: Not necessary using graph API . is possible in another technique ?

Comment: Tagging pages is not possible! You can tag people and places only

Answer (score 0):

Like said CBroe said, the bug got disabled because of too much abuse , But always there is a way , 
i know someone who did it, and this is how : he wrote a statue on facebook then he intercept the request sent from the browser and modify it to have a tag with customized text, I didn't try it but I know that it works